# Numpy: Efficient elements of array A in terms of the indices of matching elements of array B

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have some numpy array `A = [1, 2, 2, 3]` and its unique array `B = [1, 2, 3]` where array B is basically the set for array A.

I wish to get a new array `C = [0, 1, 1, 2]` that is array A but with its elements swapped for the indices of the matching elements in array B.

How would I achieve this?

Note: My arrays A and B contain 18m and 138k values respectively, so the solution must be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])
B = np.array([1, 2, 3])

res = (A[:, None] == B).argmax(1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 1 2]
```

Alternative:

```
_, res = (A[:, None] == B).nonzero()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 1 2]
```

Alternative, that should use less memory:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])
B = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# find the uniques values together with the inverse
Bp, inverse = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)

# find the indices mapping Bp to B
indices = (Bp[:, None] == B).argmax(1)

# index on the mapping
result = indices[inverse]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 1 2]
```

If `B` is **always** the unique sorted elements of A, you can do directly:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])
B = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# find the uniques values together with the inverse
_, inverse = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)

print(inverse)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 1 2]
```

Comment: NB. `np.where(condition)` is actually a shortcut for `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` ;)

Comment: Thank you! The solution worked but am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this operation? The length of my A and B are around 18m and 138k each; I'm doing this on Google Colab and it burns through RAM.

Comment: @dangtony98 dos B has unique elements?

Comment: Yes. B has all the unique elements of A.

Comment: @dangtony98 Are they sorted? How are you getting this two arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.where`:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3])
B = np.array([1, 2, 3])

C = np.where(A==B[:,None])[0]
```

output: `array([0, 1, 1, 2])`